# Why does systemd keep killing my service

Tags: linux, systemd

I would like to start an interactive script from systemd after the getty.target has been reached. This works so far, however, systemd kills the script after a couple of seconds. The systemd unit looks like the following:

```shell
[Unit]
Description = Some interactive script
Requires = getty@tty1.service
After = getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type = oneshot
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/my-script
StandardInput = tty
StandardOutput = tty
TTYPath = /dev/tty1
TTYReset = yes
TTYVHangup = yes

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Within the script there are calls to `dialog`, `mount` etc. Nothing very special but it is an interactive script. Systemd keeps killing the script and I don't understand why. The output of `systemctl status interactive-script.service` looks like:

```
● interactive-script.service - Some interactive script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/interactive-script.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2016-06-28 10:18:07 UTC; 14min ago
 Main PID: 364 (code=killed, signal=HUP)
```

And the log output gotten with `journalctl -b -u interactive-script.service` is empty:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2015-11-09 11:49:52 UTC, end at Tue 2016-06-28 10:30:28 UTC. --
```

I already tried to add **KillMode=none**, no luck. Then I tried **TimeoutStartSec=infinity** - systemd complains that it doesn't understand it therefore I tried to set it to 10000 but the script gets killed after just some seconds. I tried to run it as **Type=simple** and **Type=forking**, all to no avail.

The point is that starting the script seems to work fine (the dialogs appear) but systemd keeps killing the script. How can I achieve that systemd **does not kill this interactive script**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't relate directly to programming. It's a good fit for the Unix and Linux StackExchange site instead.

Comment: Is the time after it is killed every time the same? How many seconds? Type oneshot is not good, because systemd considers the unit started only after the process exists. Best fit is type simple. Also check the whole journal, maybe systemd logs what it decides to do with that unit...

Comment: Try using 
ExecStart = /bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/my-script